# Почему в Rust нельзя выделять память до main как это можно в C++?

Tags: rust

Есть такой код на C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int * ptr;
public:
    Foo() {
        ptr = new int;
        std::cout << "Foo constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        delete ptr;
        std::cout << "Foo destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

auto foo = Foo();

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Он компилируется и исполняется без каких-либо проблем. В нём до вызова main создаётся объект, выделяется память. Но если сделать что-то подобное в Rust, то компилятор не даст этого сделать:

```
pub static foo: Foo = Foo::new("Hello".to_string());
```

Ему не нравится функция `to_string()`, которая выделяет память. Почему Rust так разработан ? Что в этом безопасного(Rust позиционируется как безопасный системный язык программирования)?

Comment: Скорее надо задаться вопросом, почему в С++ так разрешено (чью голову посетила сия "гениальная" мысль и как ему удалось убедить остальных)?

Comment: Вопрос недостаточно конкретен. В чем, по-вашему, состоит безопасность выполнения произвольного кода в конструкторах статических объектов в неопределенном порядке до того, как контроль передается в основную точку входа программы? В Rust статические объекты могут быть инициализированы только константными выражениями, которые вычисляются на этапе компиляции (т.е. результат запекается в секции данных исполняемого файла как содержимое статической константы или, реже, переменной). Никакой код до main не выполняется, и это так задумано.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что статические выражения в Rust являются constexpr в терминах С++, constexpr-выражения тоже запрещают выделение памяти.

Причина тут не столько в безопасности, сколько в принципе "не платить за то, что не используется". Если разрешить произвольные функции при инициализации статических переменных - то одна из них может создать новый поток, который может обратиться к другой статической переменной перед её инициализацией. В итоге понадобится по мьютексу на каждую переменную (и в том же С++ так и делается!), что приедет к куче расходов на многопоточность даже в однопоточных программах.